# ASP:Checkbox Autopostback after change when the value has already been changed via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have an ASP.NET page with a checkbox and a couple of text boxes on it.

When the user unticks the checkbox, I need to do a series of checks and inform the user of the outcome. I do these checks on a postback via the checkbox autopostback property:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDecision" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Another business rule I implement is that when the checkbox is unticked and the user starts typing in one of the textboxes, I have to automatically tick the check box. I am doing this via Javascript:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLeft" runat="server" CssClass="textboxstandard" MaxLength="50" onkeyDown="SelectDecision(event);">

function SelectDecision(e) {
        if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
            var chkDec = $get('<%=chkDecision.ClientID %>');
            if (!chkDec.checked) {
                chkDec.checked = true;
            }                
        }
    }
```

All of the above works fine.

This issue I've got is that when the user starts typing in a box, the checkbox ticks. If they then manually untick the box, the postback does not fire.

Presumably this is because the checkbox is in the same state as when the page was loaded so some internal logic deems the postback unnecessary.

How can I perform the server side checks mentioned in the above scenario?

**Finalisation**
Thanks to the help given below, I was able to progress this further myself during testing of the supplied answers. I found that I could set the `AutoPostBack` attribute on the textboxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLeft" runat="server" CssClass="textboxstandard" MaxLength="50" onkeyDown="SelectDecision(event);" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

In my scenario, whilst achieving the same thing as below, I found it to be more usable as the postback occurs upon completion of editing. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thanks Pranay - I'm away from my source for the weekend, but I'll try your suggestion first thing Monday and accept your answer should it solve my issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server will not understnad client side changes. you can write javascript for checkedchange event.

you shold do as following, this function check and uncheck checkbox and fire serverside autopostback

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function SelectDecision() { 


            var chkDec = $get('<%=chkDecision.ClientID %>');                  

            //For checking or unchecking the checkbox. 
            if (chkDec .checked) { 
                chkDec .checked = false; 
            } 
            else { 
                chkDec .checked = true; 
            } 


            //For firing the click event. 
            if (document.createEventObject) { 
                // dispatch for IE 
                var evt = document.createEventObject(); 
                return element.fireEvent('on' + 'click', evt) 
            } 
            else { 
                // dispatch for firefox + others 
                var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); 
                evt.initEvent('click', true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable 
                return !element.dispatchEvent(evt); 
            } 
        } 
    </script>
```

more on : http://forums.asp.net/t/1445241.aspx/1/10

Comment: This event firing code worked better than just the straight __doPostBack call. (In IE at least). To aid future searchers - 'chkdec' should be used instead of 'element' in the event code. 'element' will give a Javascript not defined error. This retained the typed character, but it does close editing on the textbox, so you need to reset the focus (taking into account the typed character' when handling the postback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
function SelectDecision(e) {
    if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
        var chkDec = $get('<%=chkDecision.ClientID %>');
        if (!chkDec.checked) {
            chkDec.checked = true;
            __doPostBack('<%=chkDecision.ClientID %>', '');
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the javascript error "SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '__postback' is null or undefined, not a Function object " with this solution. __postback needs to be __doPostBack instead and it will fire. Unlike Pranay's answer, this one caused the character typed in the associated textbox to disappear though.

Comment: Sure, I forgot speling for function name.

Comment: Pranay's answer contains many unnecessary things, suck as checking browsing type and rising the event. When the event rises, doPostBack function will call anyway. Why you need the unnecessary things?

Comment: I only mentioned the function name to aid future searchers who happen upon this post. As I mentioned in my comment above, just calling the postback directly meant the first typed character was lost from the textbox. This didn't occur using Pranay's answer. That is the sole reason I marked his as the answer. Thankyou for your help! I greatly appreciate it! :)